# Java - Open a file with nio.file.Path class

Tags: java, nio

What I search to do is to open a file using [Desktop.open()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open-java.io.File-):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(File file);
```

but I can't find any other method using Path class instead of File.
So, my question is, can I open a file using the Path class as parameter ?

Comment: You might need to use `.open(path.toFile())`

Comment: Yes I know I can, but it's just that I'm surprised I can't find any method using Path class to open a file.

Comment: When new libraries are added, older libraries are often not updated to include them unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There are handy utility functions in the `Files` class for that.

e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newInputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-

Comment: I don't want to open a file this way, I would like to open a file like with [Desktop.open()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open-java.io.File-)

Comment: The difference being?

Comment: I just want to open a file like you can do when you double click on a movie on your desktop, I don't want to open a file to get its content

Comment: Yes, I understand now. I'd forgotten about that behavior. My apologies.